&éParsing windows dns zone file with regex
I need to parse a windows dns zone file to convert it in another format.
I use Powershell and need to extract values. Here is an example of what the file look like:
;
;  Zone NS records
;

@                       NS  servweb.test.com.
servweb.test.com.  A    31.233.196.98
@                       NS  servweb3.test.com.
servweb3.test.com. A    91.133.157.25

;
;  Zone records
;

@                       A   85.233.152.58
@                       MX  10  mail.factory.com.
@                       MX  20  mx2.factory.com.
@                       MX  50  servmail3.test.fr.
@                       TXT ( "v=spf1 include:spf.sendinblue.com mx ~all" )
@                       TXT ( "MS=ms94956023" )
_dmarc                  TXT ( "v=DMARC1; p=none; sp=none; rua=mailto:dmarc@mailinblue.com!10m; ruf=mailto:dmarc@mailinblue.com!10m; rf=afrf; pct=100; ri=86400" )
mail._domainkey         TXT ( "k=rsa;p=MIGfMA0GCSqNADCBiQKBgQDeMVIzrCa3T14JsNY0viLQBwXsa7shBD6TrBkswsFUToPyMRWC9tbR/5ey0nRBH0ZVxp+lsmTxid2Y2z+FApQ6raISgXE" )
_autodiscover._tcp      SRV 0 0 443 owa.factory.com.
_sipfederationtls._tcp  SRV 100 1 5061  sipfed.online.lync.com.
_sip._tls               SRV 100 1 443   sipdir.online.lync.com.
appli                   A   193.233.140.115
cpanel                  A   85.33.152.58
cpcalendars             A   85.33.152.58
cpcontacts              A   85.33.152.58
ftp                     CNAME   factory.com.
lyncdiscover            CNAME   webdir.online.lync.com.
mail                    A   90.115.33.93


I think I can use capture groups to extract values and use it to build my file but I'm stuck...
I tried (\S+)\s+([A-Za-z\s]+)[ \t](?=\d+) but it breaks after a few lines.
If you have any clue you'll be welcome :)
Edit: I found a quick and dirty way that fit my need but I'm sure it can be improve :)
$domains = Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\export_domaines_termines.csv -Delimiter ";"
foreach ($domain in $domains){


    $ndd = $domain.Name
    $nomfichier = "$ndd.dns"
    $records = get-content -Path "C:\temp\dns\dns\$nomfichier" | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^\;' -and $_.trim() -ne "" } | Select-Object -Skip 10
    $fichiergandi = New-Item -Path "C:\temp\dns\$nomfichier.txt" -ItemType File -Force -Confirm:$false


    foreach ($record in $records){
        $type = $prio = $value = $donnees = $name = $null
        $match = Select-String '(\S+)\s+([A-Za-z\s]+)[ \t](\S+)' -InputObject $record
        $type = $match.matches.groups[2].value

            if ($type -like "MX") {
                $match = Select-String '(\S+)\s+([A-Za-z\s]+)[ \t](\S+)[ \t](\S+)' -InputObject $record
                $name = $match.matches.groups[1].value
                $prio = $match.matches.groups[3].value
                $MX = $match.matches.groups[4].value
                "$name 10800 IN $type $prio $MX" | Out-File -FilePath $fichiergandi -Append
            }
            elseif ($type -like "TXT") {
                $match = Select-String '(\S+)\s+([A-Za-z\s]+)[ \t](\S+)[ \t]\(([^\)]+)\)' -InputObject $record
                $name = $match.matches.groups[1].value
                $donnees = ($match.matches.groups[4].value).Trim()
                "$name 10800 IN $type $donnees" | Out-File -FilePath $fichiergandi -Append
            }

            elseif ($type -like "SRV") {
                $match = Select-String '(\S+)\s+([A-Za-z\s]+)[ \t](\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)' -InputObject $record
                $name = $match.matches.groups[1].value
                $prio = $match.matches.groups[3].value
                $poids = $match.matches.groups[4].value
                $port = $match.matches.groups[5].value
                $cible = $match.matches.groups[6].value
                "$name 10800 IN $type $prio $poids $port $cible" | Out-File -FilePath $fichiergandi -Append
            }

            else {
                $name = $match.matches.groups[1].value
                $donnees = $match.matches.groups[3].value
                "$name 10800 IN $type $donnees" | Out-File -FilePath $fichiergandi -Append
            }
    }
}

I need to extract all records and build a file to import in another dns software.
The format of the file need to be :
@ 10800 IN A 85.236.152.133
@ 10800 IN MX 10 mail.example.com.
@ 10800 IN MX 20 mx2.example.com.
@ 10800 IN MX 50 servmail3.example.fr.
@ 10800 IN TXT "Sendinblue-code:022f2cda7e5e0c6d945db"
@ 10800 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:spf.sendinblue.com mx ~all"
@ 10800 IN TXT "MS=ms94956023"
_autodiscover._tcp 10800 IN SRV 0 0 443 owa.example.com.
_sipfederationtls._tcp 10800 IN SRV 100 1 5061 sipfed.online.lync.com.
_sip._tls 10800 IN SRV 100 1 443 sipdir.online.lync.com.

Each record need to be separated by one space.
I think special records like TXT or SRV need to be processed differently for example remove parenthesis but I will try to use your base.

You never explained what you are trying to extract nor what you want to end up with.  How are we supposed to help you?

Ok I edited my question. If you have a little time to comment your code it will definitively help. Thank you.

I would use a switch statement to process the file line by line. Here is my guess at what would be a useful output.
$output = switch -Regex ($zonefile){
    '^;' {
        if($_ -match ';\s+(?<Category>.+)'){
            $category = $Matches.category
        }
    }
    '^[^;\s]' {
        $_ -replace '(?<=^[^\s]*)\s+','|' -replace '(?<=^[^\s]*)\s+','|' |
            ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "|" -Header Name, Type, Value |
                Select-Object -Property @{n='Category';e={$category}},*
    }
}

# Format-Table is for viewing results only!! 
$output | Format-Table

# process the results however you desire
$output | Export-Csv ...
$output | Out-GridView

Here is the sample output

